# Tracking down python memory leak that doesn't show up in memory profilers

Tags: python, memory-leaks, aiortc

**Background:** I have a python script which sends & recieves audio using the [`aiortc`](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) library, and it generally works well (which is impressive considering I'm by no means a software developer). However, I've noticed that over multiple days the memory usage of this script slowly balloons out to fill all available memory on the host server. This only happens when the audio RTC streams are running, which rules out other parts of my code and has led me to focus exclusively on the `aiortc` library itself.

Interestingly, the usual recommended python memory tools, `tracemalloc` & `muppy`, do not show this large memory usage anywhere - the largest items in memory they can find is typically a couple MB, when the script as viewed via `htop` is using upwards of 7 GB. Example output from `muppy`:

```
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
                         str |       40749 |      6.00 MB
                        dict |       13615 |      4.83 MB
                        code |       12379 |      2.15 MB
                       tuple |       30681 |      1.91 MB
                        type |        2014 |      1.77 MB
                         set |         895 |    570.29 KB
                        list |        2457 |    526.35 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |         363 |    392.88 KB
                     weakref |        4387 |    308.46 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        4252 |    298.97 KB
                         int |        6281 |    174.71 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2461 |    173.04 KB
           getset_descriptor |        2432 |    152.00 KB
       tracemalloc.Statistic |        2337 |    127.80 KB
                   frozenset |         419 |    124.13 KB
```

This leads me to believe that the source of the leak is something lower level in the non-python libraries the `aiortc` library is calling. I'm not the only one who's reported memory leak issues with the library, but so far nobody has managed to come up with any smoking guns.

I'm curious what the recommended course of action would be to further dig into the memory usage issues I'm seeing, when the normal python memory profiling tools aren't working. Are there lower-level python memory profiling tricks, or do I need to go deeper into external memory profiling tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Leak-Checking) is worth a try?

Comment: I'd suggest trying https://github.com/vmware/chap

Comment: jemalloc worked a treat! I was able to find the culprit super quickly. It is indeed a low-level C function (av_malloc) eating up all the memory as part of the PyAV package.

Comment: Has the bug been fixed? My application that uses aiortc also leaks memory.